# Ojalgo: Handling of singular matrices

Tags: java, linear-algebra, ojalgo

I am using ojalgo to solve a (NxN) Ax = b System in java. Since there are chances that A will be a singular matrix, I would like my code to know this somehow. Is there a way? (documentation states that the `solve()` method returns one possible solution if the problem is under-qualified and the `invert()` method does not throw an exception).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the solve- and invert-methods on a BasicMatrix directly.

Switch to using an LU-decompostion instead. After you have decomposed the matrix, but before attempting the solve, you can call:

lu.isSquareAndNotSingular();

Comment: Hi Apete,

many thanks for your swift response. Could you please provide a simple code where you solve the Ax = b problem with LU-Decomposition?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To solve using LU-Decomposition try something like this.

```java
        MatrixStore M = ...equations
        MatrixStore v = ...rhs
        LU<Double> lu = LU.PRIMITIVE.make(M);
        boolean decompose = lu.decompose(M);
        MatrixStore solution;
        if(lu.isSolvable()){
            solution = lu.getSolution(v);
        // and/or check that solution is good enough
            double norm = M.multiply(solution).subtract(v).norm();
        }
```